# Keycloak - how to set timeout for http client used in keycloak library

Tags: httpclient, keycloak

I am using *keycloak-adapter-core* in version 9.0.2 and need to set a timeout for a HTTP connection between application and Keycloak server. Unfortunately, I do not see this option in the library:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_java_adapter_config
e.g. `connection-pool-size`.

I recheck also code library and I do not see that timeout is set up.

Do you know any workaround for this ?

Comment: Did you find out how to do it? I'm also struggling with this. I'm using springboot. I tried setting `connection-timeout` and `socket-timeout` but when creating the AuthzClient they are ignored. See [link](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/04da528b3517a38773c7f3afad1545cd4d1372a9/authz/client/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/client/AuthzClient.java#L264)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
socket-timeout-millis
```

in your config. [See here for reference](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/622d04920792da1e7a45e6c098bdb431d03f15fe/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/connections/httpclient/DefaultHttpClientFactory.java#L136)

Comment: I believe the question was about keycloak-adapter-core and not about keycloak. This doesn't seem to address the question.